# How to create files in a user-selected folder

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile

What I would like to do is that the user could pick a folder where my application will be able to save some configuration files, to do this I simply used the `FilePicker.platform.getDirectoryPath();` line and when the user click on a button some files are generated, to do this I added the following lines in my AndroidManifest:

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And I asked for the permissions to edit the folder using the `permission_handler` plugin with the `storage` permission but I still get this error when I try to create my files:

```
PathAccessException: Cannot create file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/TestVault/.witness' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)
```

Does anyone knows how I could fix this problem please?

Comment: Do you have a reason to ask a user to pick directory for files saving? Can you achive your feature with flow where you are storing your data in inner app directory? Inner directories don't need specific permission and you can work with it without any additional moves.

Comment: Yes, if I store my files in my app folder other apps nor the user can access it and I want my app to be sure that if they don't want to use my file browser (who will be really bad for sure) they could use external apps like Files by Google or it's iOS equivalent

Comment: How do you let the user pick a folder? And who created that folder? Android version of used device?

Comment: The folder is picked with the `FilePicker.platform.getDirectoryPath()` method, the folder can be user-created are here by default (ie. the downloads folder) and I currently do my tests on Android 12